# Creating an Interactive Map

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, dictionary, android-canvas

I am in the research stage of creating an interactive map of my school where there is a map with each room tagged where when a user clicks on the room, info is given about the teacher, class information and meeting times. The map itself would have to be zoomed in and out with limitations and moved around.

The final look of the map would be something along the lines of the middle picture [here.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yc360.college.ucauraria#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnljMzYwLmNvbGxlZ2UudWNhdXJhcmlhIl0.)

The method to create the map varies:

***Canvas Drawing***

The map could be created using the `onDraw()` method to draw rectangles representing each room. Disadvantages include the number of rectangles being drawn, and possible battery consumption. I also wouldn't know of how to go about making the map movable in a whole, so each rectangle moves together. In effect, drawing all of the rectangles to one image, and move the image.

***OpenGL***

The same method as above, but doing so in OpenGL to eliminate part of the battery consumption. Same disadvantages apply.

The main problems I face are finding and using the most efficient method and being able to implement a zoom and pan function.

What else would be possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have another alternative to suggest, but since I've more or less implemented the same functionality in my app, I recommend using OpenGL (via [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/)).  In the case rendering a single map from multiple tiles, you draw a single tile, glTranslate over to where the adjacent tile is and draw the next one, ect.

Scrolling the map is implemented by placing a glTranslate at the appropriate offset before you begin drawing your tiles.  Zooming is implemented by placing a glScale at the appropriate rate after the glTranslate.

There are, of course, equivalent canvas draw commands, but I've always found it a bit easier myself to implement such functionality using OpenGL.